# Installing FontForge on Ubuntu 14.04 SERVER

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I've tried installing FontForge both via apt-get and from source (followed instructions here: https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/blob/master/INSTALL-git.md). In both cases I receive the following output when I run execute FontForge (output below is for the version compiled from latest source).

```
ubuntu@ip-10-113-180-24:~$ fontforge 
Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by George Williams. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Based on sources from 11:18 UTC  9-Mar-2016-ML-D.
 Based on source from git with hash: a61bf687200fd87c2da5e9d172cedb8c19093e66
no xdefs_filename!
TESTING: getPixmapDir:/usr/local/share/fontforge/pixmaps
TESTING: getShareDir:/usr/local/share/fontforge
TESTING: GResourceProgramDir:/usr/local/bin
trying default theme:/usr/local/share/fontforge/pixmaps/resources
Could not open screen.
```

Does FontForge even work on Ubuntu Server? Does it require X11 to work? I installed a windowing server by following instructions at the link below but that didn't help either: https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg

Any ideas? Has no one installed FontForge on a Ubuntu Server before?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [FontForge homepage](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) it seems pretty obvious to me that is GUI application and needs x11 to work.

The error message `Could not open screen.` indicates that the installation fails because there is no X11 screen running.

You should connect to your X11 via rdp or VNC and try to install FontForge again. Probably the installer tries to open a config dialog and fails because of that.